# Toggle Button disappears in my Android's xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I have the following layout which contains a big and small surfaceview. I am adding the surfaceviews programmatically. I am using overlaying technique to put the smaller preview ontop of the bigger view. I want to add a toggle button but unfortunately the button hides itself but it works when you press the screen. My bigger sufaceview draws a bitmap while the smaller preview is displaying something else. Following is my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/small_preview"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
    </FrameLayout>
      <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you want the toggle button to appear?

Comment: At the bottom of the bigger surfaceview. The question is why it is disappearing man?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem programatecally:
I gave an Id to my FrameLayout like :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonprev"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

And afterwards:

```
btnLayout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonprev);
btnLayout.bringToFront();
```

It solved the probelm!